Black and white film with only a fish in color
One day in the high school we saw a film that I'm unable to find. I'm trying to find out the name of the film because I remember it as a great film which I cannot end to see (it was in the high school one rainy day so we only see part of the film and with a very unpleasant environment). I saw this film between 1993 and 1995 so this film has at least 20 years.
The most remarcable of this film is that it was filmed in black and white but in some scenes it appears some color. Specifically, I remember a scene with a fish tank where the only color in it was the fish (red? orange? I don't remember the exact color).
I think the film is american independent and the topic is about political activism or something like that (sorry, it's possible I'm mixing this film with others I saw in the same place and conditions, but it's possible that the specific topic was about a north american family that was scaping from the government because it's political activism).

Coppola's B&W Rumble Fish from 1983 famously has a similar scene:

You can see the scene here.

Great! That was! Thanks a lot
